# Line(x1,y1,x2,y2) using just PutPixel(x,y) example needed?

Tags: algorithm, user-interface, graphics, open-source

I need to implement Line(x1,y1,x2,y2) using just PutPixel(x,y).
And preferably without floating point numbers.
Is there any example on any language?

Answer (score 2):

You could implement [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). Here is a pseudo-code [implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#Simplification):

```
function line(x0, y0, x1, y1)
   dx := abs(x1-x0)
   dy := abs(y1-y0) 
   if x0 < x1 then sx := 1 else sx := -1
   if y0 < y1 then sy := 1 else sy := -1
   err := dx-dy

   loop
     setPixel(x0,y0)
     if x0 = x1 and y0 = y1 exit loop
     e2 := 2*err
     if e2 > -dy then 
       err := err - dy
       x0 := x0 + sx
     end if
     if e2 <  dx then 
       err := err + dx
       y0 := y0 + sy 
     end if
   end loop
```

Comment: You can avoid floating-point arithmetic by multiplying anything relevant to error by deltax and initially setting error to half of deltax.